# Can we simplify (x XOR a) + (x XOR b) + (x XOR c)?

Tags: math, bit, xor, simplify

`(x XOR a) + (x XOR b) + (x XOR c)`

Can we simplify this further?

Here '+' is addition not a logical disjunction.

`x, a, b, c` are numbers.

Example :

`x = 10 , a = 5 , b = 4 , c = 6`

`(10 XOR 5) + (10 XOR 4) + (10 XOR 6) = 41.`

Comment: using (x xor a = x'a + xa') results this [(x'a + xa') + (x'b + xb') + (x'c + xc')] => [x(a' + b' + c') + x'(a + b + c)]

Comment: What is the outcome of `XOR` -- a logical value or a number? Is `+` addition, or logical disjunction? What do you consider "simplification", as in, what operators do we have available to write out this expression and what is relevant -- the total number of symbols used, the number of times a variable is used, how much nesting there is? The best that can be said for the question as-is is that there are certainly other ways of writing this expression.

Comment: With the clarifications, I'll go on record as saying that no, this cannot be further simplified. `XOR` and `+` have no obvious relationship that allows you to simplify this. `+` can be rewritten in terms of `XOR` and `AND`, but that will not simplify things. `XOR` cannot be rewritten in terms of `+`. Of course particular combinations of inputs might be simplified (for example, if we know `x` is a power of 2 greater than `a`, `b` and `c`), but not in general. This intuition is bolstered by the fact that no C++ compiler produces anything more intelligent (aside from reordering for pipelining).